# What does this Lucene-related code actually do?

Tags: perl, lucene

```
 #usr/bin/perl
 use Plucene::Document;
 use Plucene::Document::Field;
 use Plucene::Index::Writer;
 use Plucene::Analysis::SimpleAnalyzer;
 use Plucene::Search::HitCollector;
 use Plucene::Search::IndexSearcher;
 use Plucene::QueryParser;

 my $content = "I am the law";
 my $doc = Plucene::Document->new;
 $doc->add(Plucene::Document::Field->Text(content => $content));
 $doc->add(Plucene::Document::Field->Text(author => "Philip Johnson"));


 my $analyzer = Plucene::Analysis::SimpleAnalyzer->new();
 my $writer = Plucene::Index::Writer->new("my_index", $analyzer, 1);
 $writer->add_document($doc);
 undef $writer; # close


 my $searcher = Plucene::Search::IndexSearcher->new("my_index");

 my @docs;
 my $hc = Plucene::Search::HitCollector->new(collect => sub {
         my ($self, $doc, $score) = @_;
         push @docs, $searcher->doc($doc);
 });

 $searcher->search_hc($query => $hc);
```

Try as I may, I don't understand what this code does. I understand the familiar Perl syntax and what's going on on that end...but what is a Lucene Document, Index::Writer - etc.? Most importantly, when I run this code I expect something to be generated...yet I see nothing.

I know what an Analyzer is...thanks to this doc linked to in CPAN: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/01/15/lucene.html?page=2. But I am just not getting why I run this code and it doesn't seem to DO anything...

Comment: You don't seem to be aware of the [Plucene documentation](https://metacpan.org/release/Plucene), read this first, then ask specific questions. The code above lacks the definition of the `$query` variable.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` is missing at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene is a search engine designed to search huge amounts of text very fast.

My perl is not strong, but from what I understand from Lucene objects:

```
my $content = "I am the law";
my $doc = Plucene::Document->new;
$doc->add(Plucene::Document::Field->Text(content => $content));
$doc->add(Plucene::Document::Field->Text(author => "Philip Johnson"));
```

This part creates a new document object and adds two text fields to it, content and author, in preparation to add it to an lucene index file as searchable data.

```
my $analyzer = Plucene::Analysis::SimpleAnalyzer->new();
my $writer = Plucene::Index::Writer->new("my_index", $analyzer, 1);
$writer->add_document($doc);
undef $writer; # close
```

This part creates the index files and adds the previously created document do that index. At this point, you should have a "my_index" folder with several index files in it, in your application directory, with docs's data in it as searchable text.

```
my $searcher = Plucene::Search::IndexSearcher->new("my_index");

my @docs;
my $hc = Plucene::Search::HitCollector->new(collect => sub {
       my ($self, $doc, $score) = @_;
       push @docs, $searcher->doc($doc);
});

$searcher->search_hc($query => $hc);
```

This part attempts to search the index file created above for the same document data you just used to create the index file. Presumably, you'll have your search results in @docs at this point, which you might want to display to user (tho it is not, in this sample).

This seems to be a "hello world" application for Lucene usage in perl. In real-life applications, I dont see a scenario where you would create the index file and then search it from same piece of code.

Comment: Oh wow...I have found my_index and effectively gotten it to do SOMETHING. That is much further than I just was. Thanks for this insight.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get this code from? It is a copy of the code in the *Synopsis* at the start of the [`Plucene`](https://metacpan.org/module/Plucene) POD documentation.

I guess it was an attempt by someone to begin learning about `Plucene`. The code in a module's synopsis isn't necessarily meant to achieve something useful on its own.

As the documentation you refer to says, *Lucene is a Java library that adds text indexing and searching capabilities to an application. It is not a complete application that one can just download, install, and run.*

Where did you get the idea that you should run the code you show?

Comment: Ah - I see - well it was ME that copied it. It was MY attempt and now that I think about it... you are right about synopsis code rarely doing anything, only showing basic usage. I originated this idea from panic. 

I wonder, then, what I should run. I went to this site and saw if this example ran:

http://everything2.com/title/Plucene

But same results of running and nothing created. I would really love a working example to show me how Lucene really works... but I fear there may not be an example readily available (oh woe is me - I may have to dig).